# Sonar-checkstyle plugin is not working as expected

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle, sonarqube-scan

I am using **sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.5-SNAPSHOT** , I created a Quality profile Called Checkstyle and activated all rules,
Execution stops everytime when it comes to checkstyle stage. 
I tried executing this again by using just 1 rule from checkstyle repository , thinking that it may be some rule thats doing it. but that also didnt work. 
Only time execution was succesful when there were no rules enabled.

I am new in sonarqube and in dire need of help.

here is the log of my execution :

```
D:\SONAR_QUBE\sonar-scanner-2.5.1\bin\..
INFO: Scanner configuration file: D:\SONAR_QUBE\sonar-scanner-2.5.1\bin\..\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: D:\Ashu\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\java\sonar-runner\java-sonar-runner-simple\sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.5.1
INFO: Java 1.8.0_73 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\IC020829\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load global repositories
INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=184ms
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\IC020829\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=10ms
INFO: SonarQube server 5.3
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=27ms
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Apply project exclusions
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=50ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=1825ms
INFO: SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: -------------  Scan Ashu_Test_Project
INFO: Language is forced to java
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=1055ms
INFO: Base dir: D:\Ashu\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\java\sonar-runner\java-sonar-runner-simple
INFO: Working dir: D:\Ashu\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\java\sonar-runner\java-sonar-runner-simple\.sonar
INFO: Source paths: src
INFO: Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_US
INFO: Index files
INFO: 2 files indexed
INFO: Quality profile for java: CheckStyle
INFO: JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : D:\Ashu\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\java\sonar-runner\java-sonar-runner-simple\target\jacoco.exec
INFO: JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: D:\Ashu\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\java\sonar-runner\java-sonar-runner-simple\target\jacoco-it.exec
INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor
INFO: Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): none
INFO: JavaClasspath initialization...
INFO: Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of source files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.libraries property
INFO: JavaClasspath initialization done: 0 ms
INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization...
INFO: Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of test files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.test.libraries property
INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization done: 0 ms
INFO: Java Main Files AST scan...
INFO: 2 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Java Main Files AST scan done: 1592 ms
INFO: Java bytecode has not been made available to the analyzer. The org.sonar.java.bytecode.visitor.DependenciesVisitor@615b5480 are disabled.
INFO: Java Test Files AST scan...
INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Java Test Files AST scan done: 0 ms
INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=2574ms
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
INFO: 2/2 source files have been analyzed
INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Sensor QProfileSensor
INFO: Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=61ms
INFO: Sensor SurefireSensor
INFO: parsing D:\Ashu\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\java\sonar-runner\java-sonar-runner-simple\target\surefire-reports
INFO: Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor SmellMeasuresSensor
INFO: Sensor SmellMeasuresSensor (done) | time=149ms
INFO: Sensor CheckstyleSensor
INFO: Execute Checkstyle 6.12.1...
INFO: Checkstyle configuration: D:\Ashu\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\java\sonar-runner\java-sonar-runner-simple\.sonar\checkstyle.xml
INFO: Checkstyle charset: windows-1252
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.Closeables.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.PackageNamesLoader.getPackageNames(PackageNamesLoader.java:156)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.finishLocalSetup(Checker.java:137)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:134)
        at org.sonar.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleExecutor.execute(CheckstyleExecutor.java:84)
        at org.sonar.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleSensor.analyse(CheckstyleSensor.java:57)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:98)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:185)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:238)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:274)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:165)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:152)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:133)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:82)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:66)
```

Comment: You should notify the Checkstyle team about the issue. Meanwhile I recommend to use the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen quite a few times such a problem. This usually happens when your system is working at an environment within a limited access or a proxy setting that have restrictions or limitations.

On the other hand I think the problem you are facing is because of the compatibility conflict. Here is the link to find the compatible version of **Checkstyle** to configure in your SonarQube.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix

For me if your plugin is not compatible with your SonarQube then Sonar should not start but I can see you have started it successfully and moved ahead to the step of quality profile and analyzing your project.

Comment: I have tried using this plugin on different versions of SonarQube also ...... it integrates well with all of them .... but the problem still remain same while execution.